# how to write wifi config to nfc tag using android studio and java?

Tags: android, wifi, nfc

how to write wifi hotspot configuration to nfc tag using app written in java? ive read Near Field Communication with Android Cookbook and its chapter about configuring a wifi network. but this example is not working anymore and its kinda hard for me to determine the reason why.
app structure:
activity_main.xml with ssid and password input fields,a spinner with security type and a button to start writing
MainActivity.java with code that writes this info to nfc tag

is there a simple way to solve this?

ive found this file:
https://github.com/bparmentier/WiFiKeyShare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/be/brunoparmentier/wifikeyshare/utils/NfcUtils.java

but have no idea how to properly change this code to met my needs

Comment: The question is what are your needs? If you want it simpler than a couple of hundred lines of code for an App, then why do it yourself. Writing the Wifi config to NFC card is built in the Android OS, a swipe and 3 presses and your done.

Comment: i used "simple" cuz code from the following link is too much for this needs. i just ask for a working example of clean code that can solve the fllowing issue without extra functions

Answer (score 0):

Working Example of how it is done in the Android OS (what my swipe and presses run)

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WriteWifiConfigToNfcDialog.java